# Every Dunford-Pettis operator is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, compact-operators

I was trying this problem.

Let $X$ be a Banach space that does not contain a copy of $l^1$. Show that every Dunford-Pettis operator $T: X \rightarrow Y$, with $Y$ any Banach space, is compact.

I know if $X$ is reflexive, then any Dunford-Pettis operator is compact. But I don't know how to use it here. Also, is it possible to come up with a solution without using the Rosenthal's $l^1$ theorem?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Using a bit of a sledgehammer, if $X$ does not contain $\ell_1$ and if $(x_n)$ is bounded in $X$, then $(x_n)$ has a weakly Cauchy subsequence $(y_i)$.  For two strictly increasing sequences $(n_i)$ and $(m_i)$ of positive integers, the sequence $(y_{n_i}-y_{m_i})$ converges weakly to $0$. Its image then converges in norm to $0$ since $T$ is Dunford-Pettis. So $(Ty_n)$ is norm-Cauchy...

Comment: @DavidMitra, That works. Do you have anything on your mind without using Rosenthal's theorem?

Comment: No. I'm somewhat certain though (given the generality of the statement) that it's needed here.

Comment: Actually in the book Albiac, Kalton it appears later. So that's why. But anyway thanks for the solution.

Comment: Yes, but they mention the theorem earlier. (Not that that means much.)

Comment: @DavidMitra, I don't think they mention before this chapter.